# Don't trigger onChange if same option is selected in react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

The *onChange* of a react-select drop down is getting triggered when I select an already selected value in the drop down. Is there a way to configure react-select to not trigger *onChange* event if already selected value is selected again.

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pkm6o021q) link. Try selecting Purple and you can see the logs in console. Below is the same code in case you want to see it right away.

```
import chroma from 'chroma-js';

import { colourOptions } from './docs/data';
import Select from 'react-select';

const dot = (color = '#ccc') => ({
  alignItems: 'center',
  display: 'flex',

  ':before': {
    backgroundColor: color,
    borderRadius: 10,
    content: '" "',
    display: 'block',
    marginRight: 8,
    height: 10,
    width: 10,
  },
});

const colourStyles = {
  control: styles => ({ ...styles, backgroundColor: 'white' }),
  option: (styles, { data, isDisabled, isFocused, isSelected }) => {
    const color = chroma(data.color);
    return {
      ...styles,
      backgroundColor: isDisabled
        ? null
        : isSelected ? data.color : isFocused ? color.alpha(0.1).css() : null,
      color: isDisabled
        ? '#ccc'
        : isSelected
          ? chroma.contrast(color, 'white') > 2 ? 'white' : 'black'
          : data.color,
      cursor: isDisabled ? 'not-allowed' : 'default',
    };
  },
  input: styles => ({ ...styles, ...dot() }),
  placeholder: styles => ({ ...styles, ...dot() }),
  singleValue: (styles, { data }) => ({ ...styles, ...dot(data.color) }),
};

const logConsole = (selectedVal) => {
  console.log(selectedVal)
}

export default () => (
  <Select
    defaultValue={colourOptions[2]}
    label="Single select"
    options={colourOptions}
    styles={colourStyles}
    onChange={logConsole}
  />
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution would be to hide the selected value using the `hideSelectedOptions` prop.

```
<Select
    { ... }
    hideSelectedOptions
/>
```

Another solution would be to change your `Select` component into a controlled component and check in the `onChange` handler, if the selected value does match the currently selected value, then simply do nothing.

```
class MySelect extends Component {
    state = {
       value: null
    }

    onChange = (selectedValue) => {
        const { value } = this.state;
        if (value && value.value === selectedValue.value) return;

        // Do whatever you want here

        this.setState({ value: selectedValue });
    }

    render = () => (
        <Select
            { ... }
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.onChange}
        />
    );
}
```